# How can I edit the pairing alert view

Tags: ios, alert, core-bluetooth

I am developing an **iOS 6 app** that pairs with a custom **BLE device**.

When the user wants to pair, an alert message appears (directly form core bluetooth I guess) and the user can either push "**Pair**" or "**Cancel**".

However the title and body of the alert message are empty showing "**PAIRING_TITLE**" and "**PAIRING_BODY**".

How can I write a specific content for these two variables? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed, that alert view is shown by the system and *cannot be customized*. I suppose it is the simulator that is causing those messages to be shown instead of some meaningful text. This can never happen on an actual device. Recommendation from Apple is not to use the simulator for development of BLE stuff. It is very likely that it won't be possible in the near future anyway.

Comment: Thanks! You are right! I checked it on a iOS device and the alert view shows proper information.